# bash, test if curl exists, and install if it does not

Tags: bash, curl, sudo

I googled many solutions but did not find one that fully worked. My own rough working is:

```
[ $(which curl) -eq "" ] || sudo apt install curl
```

This doesn't quite work, saying "unary operator expected". I've tried `=` or `==`, so I'm not getting how to do a test like this. Is it possible that the empty output from `which curl` is a $null and I have to test for that?

Alternatively, is there a way to just run `sudo apt install curl` and then `2>&null` at the end to suppress if it's already installed?

Comment: The trivial fix is to quote the command substitution. Sure you can run `sudo apt -y install curl >/dev/null 2>&1` but that is going to fail or hang if the user does not have their `sudo` password cached.

Comment: @YorSubs : Technically speaking, you don't test whether an executable `curl` exists, you just test whether it exists **and is in your PATH**. Also, you don't know whether (whatever is hidden behind the name _curl_) is that curl in that version you need. One alternative would be to run `curl --version` and parse its output.

Comment: I see your point. Would testing for `/usr/bin/curl` be more rigorous (I don't need completely bulletproof, and it would be very odd for someone to put a file there that was not a downloaded version of `curl`). My only question then is: do different distros put `curl` in different places, or would `/usr/bin/curl` be a reliable cross-platform location?

Comment: Not only can other distros put curl elsewhere, they can also use a different installer than apt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`which` returns a failure if it doesn't find the program, so you can

```
which curl &> /dev/null || sudo apt install curl
```

Note that if someone has a different program in $PATH named curl, the script can still fail later.

`-eq` compares numbers, not strings.

Comment: haha that's a creative way to remain shell-portable, thanks!